# Get all the records of column in Spring Data JPA, even we specify it as parameter

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, spring-data-jpa

There is a table called `zipcode` with columns as `id, zip, city, state`.

In our case, we want to get the records based on either `id` or `zip` or `city` or `state`.

The General **SQL** query looks like

```
SELECT * FROM zipcode WHERE id=id AND zip=zip AND city=city AND state=state;
```

If we want to get a specific state then, we will replace the state value with the given name.

```
SELECT * FROM zipcode WHERE id=id AND zip=zip AND city=city AND state='California';
```

If we want a specific city, then we can write

```
SELECT * FROM zipcode WHERE id=id AND zip=zip AND city='Los Angles' AND state=state;
```

The problem with Spring Data JPA is, if we write a method

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM zipcode WHERE id=?1 AND zip=?2 AND city=?3 AND state=?4", nativeQuery = true)
List<Zipcode> getZipCodes(Integer id, Integer zip, String city, String state)
```

I want to get all the cities but a specific state only, then I can't use this method, like how I can use the above SQL query, where we just need to replace the column value.

How can we achieve this in Spring Data JPA, using native query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use spring data jpa query params

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM zipcode WHERE id=:id AND (zip=:zip or :zip is null) AND  (city=:city or :city is null)  AND (state=:state or :state is null) ", nativeQuery = true)
List<Zipcode> getZipCodes(@Param("id") Integer id, @Param("zip") Integer zip, @Praram("city) String city, @Param("state") String state)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Spring Data has a way of doing this in a single method, but you could try using an Example:

```
public List<Zipcode> getZipcodes(Integer id, Integer zip, String city, String state){
  Zipcode zipcode = new Zipcode();
  if (id != null)
    zipcode.setId(id);
  if (zip != null)
    zipcode.setZip(zip);
  ...
  return zipcodeRepository.findAll(Example.of(zipcode));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM zipcode WHERE  (id=?1 or ?1 is null) AND (zip=?2 or ?2 is null) AND  (city=?3 or ?3 is null)  AND (state=?4 or ?4 is null) ", nativeQuery = true)
List<Zipcode> getZipCodes(Integer id, Integer zip, String city, String state)
```